# flycheck hides compilation errors

Tags: flycheck

I use Emacs to edit Go files. When I compile them I can use `next-error` to jump to the next error in a specific Go file. Very handy. However, when I also enable flycheck on my Go file for on-the-fly syntax checking, it somehow conflicts with the error reporting of the compilation. What I mean is when I compile a Go file that contains errors (not syntactic but semantic errors), the compilation window correctly shows the errors, but `next-error` doesn't work: it just displays the message:

```
No more Flycheck errors
```

If I disable Flycheck in the buffer, `next-error` works again correctly. It's as if Flycheck has hidden compilation errors. (I looked at `next-error` documentation and it does say it should cycle through all errors, but it doesn't do it in my case.) Emacs version:

GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.10.7) of 2014-03-07 on lamiak, modified by Debian

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default Flycheck hooks into the standard error navigation of Emacs to make error navigation for Flycheck as simple as possible.

You can disable this feature by setting `flycheck-standard-error-navigation` to `nil`.  Emacs' standard bindings will now ignore Flycheck's errors.  You can still navigate these with Flycheck's own navigation bindings `C-c ! n` and `C-c ! p`.